# Comparing lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of test results.  The test results are represented as dictionaries:

```
list1 = [{testclass='classname', testname='testname', testtime='...},...]
list2 = [{testclass='classname', testname='testname', ...},...]
```

The dictionary representation is slightly different in both lists, because for one list I have some
more information.  But in all cases, every test dictionary in either list will have a classname and testname element which together effectively form a way of uniquely identifying the test and a way to compare it across lists.

I need to figure out all the tests that are in list1 but not in list2, as these represent new test failures.

To do this I do:

```
def get_new_failures(list1, list2):
    new_failures = []
    for test1 in list1:
        for test2 in list2:
            if test1['classname'] == test2['classname'] and \
                    test1['testname'] == test2['testname']:
                break; # Not new breakout of inner loop
        # Doesn't match anything must be new
        new_failures.append(test1);
    return new_failures;
```

I am wondering is a more python way of doing this.  I looked at filters. The function the filter uses would need to get a handle to both lists.  One is easy, but I am not sure how it would get a handle to both.  I do know the contents of the lists until runtime.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_new_failures(list1, list2):
    check = set([(d['classname'], d['testname']) for d in list2])
    return [d for d in list1 if (d['classname'], d['testname']) not in check]
```

Comment: +1, this was the next thought I had -- I didn't notice you had posted it.

Answer (score 2):

If each combination of `classname` and `testname` is truly unique, then the more computationally efficient approach would be to use two dictionaries instead of two lists. As key to the dictionary, use a tuple like so: `(classname, testname)`. Then you can simply say `if (classname, testname) in d: ...`.

If you need to preserve insertion order, and are using Python 2.7 or above, you could use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module.

The code would look something like this:

```
tests1 = {('classname', 'testname'):{'testclass':'classname', 
                                     'testname':'testname',...}, 
         ...}
tests2 = {('classname', 'testname'):{'testclass':'classname', 
                                     'testname':'testname',...}, 
         ...}

new_failures = [t for t in tests1 if t not in tests2]
```

If you must use lists for some reason, you could iterate over `list2` to generate a set, and then test for membership in that set:

```
test1_tuples = ((d['classname'], d['testname']) for d in test1)
test2_tuples = set((d['classname'], d['testname']) for d in test2)
new_failures = [t for t in test1_tuples if t not in test2_tuples]
```

Comment: your code works great, but it has a typo in the `test2_tuples = ...` line - a parenthesis is missing

Answer (score 2):

To compare two dict `d1` and `d2` on a subset of their keys, use:

```
all(d1[k] == d2[k] for k in ('testclass', 'testname'))
```

And if your two list have the same lenght, you can use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to pair them.

Comment: @senderle: If he has two list, I don't see the problem in that.